# AngularJS: Component communication - interpolate child content

Tags: angularjs, components, communication

Here is an official example of [intercomponent communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)

I want a little different behavior. Lets say, I want pane content to be a tab name.

For example

```
<my-tabs>
  <my-pane>Hello</my-pane>
  <my-pane>World</my-pane>
</my-tabs>
```

And then in parent template I tried something like this, but it does not work.

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="pane in $ctrl.panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">
      <a href="" ng-click="$ctrl.select(pane)"><div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you will manually need to get the transcluded content and set it as the title. Change the controller of tab-pane as follows:

```
 controller: function($transclude) {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      $transclude(clone => {
        this.title = clone.text();
      });

      this.tabsCtrl.addPane(this);
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have a question though - so I still need to have hidden <div ng-transclude> in the parent template, right? Seems like we going to render child content twice